# How to make a nodejs chat server manage different type of data?

Tags: node.js, chat

I've made a simple nodejs chat server using the "net" framework. It works by adding to an array of clients a socket with all data of the client (when the client connects). The client is written in c#.

The problem is that the server just receives and sends messages without knowing the content of them, and I would like to find a way to send the clients' usernames to the server which will use the usernames to identify the sockets and send the data of the active sockets (the usernames) to a client which connects.

```
net = require('net')

var clients = [];

var srv = net.Server(function (socket) {

clients.push(socket);
console.log("a client connected.");

socket.on('data', function (msg_sent) {
    for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
        if (clients[i] == socket) 
          continue;
        clients[i].write(msg_sent);
    }
console.log("a message has been sent.");
});

socket.on('end', function () {
      clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);  
  console.log("a client disconnected.");
});

srv.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: It's not clear where your problem is. It seems you have to choose your architecture. The simplest one : send a structure containing both the username and the text instead of sending just the text.

Comment: how can the server understand that a structure has been sent? and how can it read it?